# How to convert this spring boot sample app so a war file is built that can run in an external Tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to figure out how to convert this sample spring boot app so that the war file that gets generated can run in an external Tomcat server: [enter link description here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web/tree/master/complete)

Here is my modiefied pom.xml which does generate the war file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-securing-web</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Here is my new Application class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplicationOLD.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationOLD.class, args);
}

}
```

In the console, I can see that the app has been started by Tomcat:

> 2017-07-14 16:53:10.736  INFO 12020 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application v0.1.0 on LAPTOP-I1Q04POH with PID 12020 (C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\webapps\gs-securing-web-0.1.0\WEB-INF\classes started by akova in C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22\bin)
>   2017-07-14 16:53:10.740  INFO 12020 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>   2017-07-14 16:53:11.012  INFO 12020 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5f4f198c: startup date [Fri Jul 14 16:53:11 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-07-14 16:53:11.209  INFO 12020 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 197 ms
>   2017-07-14 16:53:11.256  INFO 12020 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
>   2017-07-14 16:53:11.295  INFO 12020 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 1.118 seconds (JVM running for 3.925)

But I can't see to access the app when I go to the url in a browser.  I get an HTTP 404 error using the url: http://localhost:8080/gs-securing-web-0.1.0/.

What am I missing???  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the porject](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web) itself, and the tutorial to followed to build this porject, you should use only this URI: http://localhost:8080/ to consume your service.

Use http://localhost:8080/hello and  http://localhost:8080/login for the other resouces.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency under dependencies section

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```